# Why do we need a return address?

Tags: assembly, stack

On a call stack, we have a frame pointer which gives us the location of the arguments to a procedure and the address of a pointer to the previous frame. We also have a return address. Why it the return address necessary? Could we not just follow the frame pointers back up the stack, popping off the stack frames as we went? Is the return address just an optimisation?

Comment: Return address contains the address of the instruction to return to. It's not otherwise stored anywhere else.

Comment: Frame pointer is generally the previous stack pointers. The return address is the previous instruction pointer.

Comment: A frame is optional, a frame pointer is optional, a return address is not optional.  Also heavily optimized inside the processor to improve branch prediction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The return address does not point to the previous stack frame, it points into the code segment to the next instruction in the calling method.

Comment: "Into the code segment" -> This was what reminded my sleep deprived brain how stupid I was being. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

return address refers to address of the code segment or instruction whose function call has created that stack.It is very important data as per vulnerabilities, as in case of buffer overrun,attackers get address space which can lead to compromising state

Answer (score 0):

The frame points to storage space for parameters and local variables. You can bring that in the original state, but that won't restore the instruction pointer, the old value of which was lost when a call to a function was made.

The return address is just that, the saved instruction pointer.